# How to become more well-received

Tags: support

When I just started to compose a [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632340/does-etckeeper-disrupt-installations-from-software-center) I got the following message:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of [being blocked from asking any more](https://askubuntu.com/help/question-bans).
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: [How do I ask a
>   good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Since I only have asked two questions so far I quickly reviewed them. [One of them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413835/what-logfile-contains-time-of-startup-and-shutdown) has (at least) two upvotes but was rightfully closed as a duplicate and [the other one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318131/clean-uninstall-of-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper) has an accepted answer and (at least) four upvotes.

What am I expected to do in order to become a more "well-received" member of this community and also to reduce my "danger of being blocked"?

Comment: This must be some bug.

Comment: Deleted posts count too. Do you have any deleted, negatively received posts?

Comment: @muru No, I have not. I suspect the closed as duplicate one to have a bad influence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I don't think you've done anything wrong. The system does and I don't know why.

You have two questions that were automatically deleted because they didn't get enough attention. They weren't voted in either direction. I *suspect* these counted against you but the accounting isn't made public (even to moderators) so I'm not entirely sure.

I don't think they *should* count as bad questions.

I have asked on MSE (the meta site for all the Stack Exchange sites) [that SE adjust the way they tally the score on people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257964/144180) but I have a fairly mixed record on MSE. What's in *our* interest isn't always in the interest of the whole network.

Either way, if you do find yourself with a question-block and you think it's unfair, come and bother a moderator on here (we get alerts) or [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room). We can't do anything about it directly but we can harrass peole who can.